# Make div height equal to its parent (100%)

Tags: html, css, height

I have a main div that contains two other divs. I need that the first one must have the same height of the parent div. The parent div height is not specified in CSS.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/x8dhnh4L/
The pink div must expand to the full height of the parent (red border).

One solution I tried is using `display:flex`, but it's not IE-friendly (I need a IE8+ compatibility). Plus I'd like to achieve this with CSS only, so I'm avoiding JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a table layout:

- set display:table on the parent
- set display:table-cell to the childs that need the same height

  ```
  #container {
      position: relative;
      width:600px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      display:table;
  }

  #content {
      display: table-cell;
      background-color:pink;
      width:400px;
  }

  #side-bar {
      display:table-cell;
      background-color:yellow;
      width:170px;
      padding-left:25px;
      vertical-align: top;
  }
  ```

here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/x8dhnh4L/2/

As noted in the comments, margins do not work in elements with `display:table-cell`. If acceptable, you can use `padding-left` instead of `margin-left`...
You could also add an additional `<div>` to separate the 2 columns by 25px.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the margin "workaround". I will mark your solution as the best if no one comes with something better.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/x8dhnh4L/1/

Set side bar to

```
float:right;
```

and set content

```
height:100%;
```

Comment: #content must be at least the same size of #side-bar.

Comment: that does not make sense. You said The pink div must expand to the full height of the parent (red border). Which is what I did. Please clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: He has explained what he's trying to achieve perfectly, he simply wants the  content divs height taking up 100% of it's parent div. It's not rocket science. :)

Comment: he said: "I need that the first one must have the same height of the parent div. " Which is what I did. he also said: "The pink div must expand to the full height of the parent (red border).". Where is his question do you see him say that he wants the parent div to expand and contain both child divs?

Comment: Well it's common sense that he would want both child divs inside the parent... haha. It just looks really messed up otherwise.

Comment: Yes it does look bad, but that is not what he asked for. Next time someone asks a question i'll just make a random assumption of what they want instead of what they actually asked for, thanks for the common sense advice sir.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to use `display:table` for `#container` and `height:100%` for `#content`.

http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/x8dhnh4L/5/

Comment: I dont have ie8 to check this

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the "#content" div to expand to "#container" height, you need to set a height for parent div "#container" and height and float for "#content"

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width:600px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 800px; //whatever height you need
}

#content {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:pink;
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
}
```

This way "#content" height will adjust to "#container" height, but "#side-bar" will take the height it needs to show it's content.

With Hanoncs solution the parent div "#container" will adjust to child's div "#content" height.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way around this is using `display: table;` declaration on the parent element and `display: table-cell;` declaration on the child element.

I would recommend reading [Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS and No Hacks](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

put:

```
display: grid;
```

on the parent - if it only has one child, the child will resize to the same size as the parent